# Как сделать чтоб определенная страница на которой я нахожусь подсвечивалась?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Сейчас делаю пагинацию, мне приходят данные по апи и я их разбиваю на определенное количество страниц но столкнулся с проблемой - не получается выделить текущую страницу на которой я нахожусь, мне ее нужно как-то подсветить. Думал сделать как-то через стейт но выходит коряво, к примеру:
const [active, setActive] = React.useState(false) - и потом в функции paginate setActive(true).

Мой код:

```js
 const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = React.useState<number>(1);
  const [countriesPerPage, setCountriesPerPage] = React.useState<number>(10);

  const lastCountryIndex = currentPage * countriesPerPage;
  const firstCountryIndex = lastCountryIndex - countriesPerPage;
  const currentCountry = filteredCountries.slice(firstCountryIndex, lastCountryIndex);

  const paginate = (pageNumber: any) => {
    setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
  };
  
  <Pagination
        countriesPerPage={countriesPerPage}
        totalCountriess={countries.length}
        paginate={paginate}
      />
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Код пагинации:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./Pagination.css";

export default function Pagination({
  countriesPerPage,
  totalCoins,
  paginate,
}: any) {
  const pageNumbers = [];

  for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(totalCountries / countriesPerPage); i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="pagination">
        {pageNumbers.map((number) => (
          <li key={number}>
            <button className="page-link" onClick={() => paginate(number)}>
              {number}
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В компонент `Pagination` добавить проп `currentPage`

```
<Pagination
        countriesPerPage={countriesPerPage}
        totalCountriess={countries.length}
        paginate={paginate}
        currentPage={currentPage}
      />
```

Внутри компонента заимпортить либу `classnames` и добавить клас активной кнопки

```
import React from "react";
import classNames from "classnames"
import "./Pagination.css";

export default function Pagination({
  countriesPerPage,
  totalCoins,
  paginate,
  currentPage
}: any) {
  const pageNumbers = [];

  for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(totalCountries / countriesPerPage); i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="pagination">
        {pageNumbers.map((number) => (
          <li key={number}>
            <button className={classNames("page-link", {"page-link-active": number === currentPage})} onClick={() => paginate(number)}>
              {number}
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Вариант 1:

Передавать значение в компонент **Paginate** в качестве **props** и выставлять определённый класс элементу

```
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = React.useState<number>(1);
const [countriesPerPage, setCountriesPerPage] = React.useState<number>(10);

const lastCountryIndex = currentPage * countriesPerPage;
const firstCountryIndex = lastCountryIndex - countriesPerPage;
const currentCountry = filteredCountries.slice(firstCountryIndex, lastCountryIndex);

const paginate = (pageNumber: any) => {
  setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
};

<Pagination
  countriesPerPage={countriesPerPage}
  totalCountriess={countries.length}
  paginate={paginate}
  active={currentPage} // Передаем активную страницу
/>


export default function Pagination({
                                     countriesPerPage,
                                     totalCoins,
                                     paginate,
                                     active
                                   }: any) {
  const pageNumbers = [];

  for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(totalCountries / countriesPerPage); i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="pagination">
        {pageNumbers.map((number) => (
          <li key={number}>
            // Если номер страницы равен активному, дописываем класс(например active)
            <button className={'page-link' + (active === number) ? ' active' : ''} onClick={() => paginate(number)}>
              {number}
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Вариант 2:

Сохранять состояние в компоненте **Paginate**, при условии, что оно не отмонтируется в приложении.

```
export default function Pagination({
                                     countriesPerPage,
                                     totalCoins,
                                     paginate
                                   }: any) {
  const pageNumbers = [];
  const [activePage, setActivePage] = useState(1);

  for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(totalCountries / countriesPerPage); i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="pagination">
        {pageNumbers.map((number) => (
          <li key={number}>
            <button 
              className={'page-link' + (activePage === number) ? ' active' : ''} 
              onClick={() => {
                paginate(number)
                setActivePage(number);
              }}>
              {number}
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

В обоих вариантах, разметка активной страницы выполняется в методе map, в которм можно однозначно оперделить текущую страницу. Это, на мой взгляд, самый правильный вариант.

Как из вариантов вам больше подходит - решать вам.

Comment: У меня в таком случае получается что каждая из 25 кнопок 'active', класс применяется к каждой... Значит у меня не верно работает currentPage ?

Comment: Задал currentPage не 1 а 4, данные отобразились с 4 страницы, значит ошибка по-идеи в другом.

Comment: Добавьт вывод в консоль, какой activePage у вас рассчитался и с чем сравнивается. И какой из вариантов вы сейчас смотрите?

Comment: @Somebody И еще... Вы передаете `totalCountriess={countries.length}` при этом в основном компоненте **countries** не представлен + в компоненте **Pagination** у вас пропс **totalCoins** а вы рассчитываете **totalCountries** / countriesPerPage. Проверьте эти данные

Comment: Извиняюсь за опечатки, копировал с другого проекта. Ошибок в пропсах нет.

Comment: Попробовал оба варианта - одна и та же проблема, все active. Если делать вторым способом и в консоли проверить activePage то будет 1, при переключении на вторую страницу - 2 и тд. Точно так же в первом варианте - currentPage дает 1 и тд

Comment: Проверяйте, какое значение у вас сохраняется в active и с чем оно сравнивается. Если вы говорите, что каждая кнопка выделена, то может где то допущена ошибка в именах переменных. Ну не может число  1 быть равным 5 по определению...

Comment: Не знаю в чем ошибка, вроде все верно. У меня получилось с библиотекой classnames